# How to delete checked row from db

Tags: php, checkbox, delete-row, sql-delete

I have this deleting sql but can't seem to find out why it's not working :/

After trying to delete a checked row the if($result) does reload the page but the row is still there ... :/

Can someone please help me ?
What am I missing ?

```
<form name="delete_posts" method="post" action="">
        <table class="all_posts">
            <tr>
                <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" /></td>
                <td class="post_title">Title</td>
                <td>Auther</td>
                <td>Posted</td>
                <td>Updated</td>
                <td>Category</td>

            </tr>
            <tr><td class="delete_posts" colspan="6"><input name="delete" type="submit"     
id="delete" value="delete"></td></tr>

<?php 

    $post_set = get_all_posts();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($post_set)){

        echo "<tr>
                <td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[]\" value=".$row['id']."></td>
                <td><a href=\"edit_post.php?edit=".$row['id']."\">" .$row['title']. "</td>
                <td>Auther</td>
                <td>".date("d. M. 'y", strtotime($row["date"]))."</td>
                <td>Update Date</td>
                <td>".str_replace("_"," ",$row['category'])."</td>
            </tr>";}


// Delete Posts

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $checkbox = $_POST['delete'];
    $count = count($checkbox);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $del_id ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php 
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=posts.php\">";
}
}
?>

</table>                
</form>
```

Thanx for helping

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an error in your code where you retrive the checked row : instead of getting the checkbox values (`$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];`) you are getting the delete value (`$checkbox = $_POST['delete'];`).

Here is the corrected part :

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $count = count($checkbox);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $del_id ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
```

Comment: I need to mention that this is bad code that can result in mysql injection. You should never pass unchecked input directly to a mysql query.

Comment: Perfect! This Worked thank you very much of course I have to get the value of the checkbox ! :) I'll accept your answer momentarily

Comment: I didn't tried to secure his code, just helping him to get it working ;). @Chris : good, don't hesitate to come back to validate the answer :)